# Asp.Net MVC Codefirst Model Relation to the Same Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a model and i want to put an extra field which can be populated form the same model. IE: Categories and and sub-categories.

In my example, visitor can add an filetype but if file type is under an another file type, he can choose, 
But i cant work it out. Below you can see my model.

```
 public class HrFileType
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dosya Adı")]
        public int Name { get; set; }

        public int? HrFileTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual HrFileType HrFileType2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `ForeignKeyAttribute` like below:

```
public class HrFileType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Dosya Adı")]
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int? HrFileTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HrFileTypeId")]
    public virtual HrFileType HrFileType2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can also use fluent API to achieve this:

```
public class HrFileType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Dosya Adı")]
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int? HrFileTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual HrFileType HrFileType2 { get; set; }
}

public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<HrFileType> HrFileTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //
        modelBuilder.Entity<HrFileType>()
                    .HasOptional(c => c.HrFileType2)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.HrFileTypeId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i am trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listing the other file types?

```
 public class HrFileType
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dosya Adı")]
        public int Name { get; set; }

        public List<HrFileType> RelatedTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

then using Entity Frameworks fluent API in the DbContext, try explicitly declaring a many to many map.

```
modelbuilder.Entity<HrFileType>().HasMany(x => x.RelatedTypes).WithMany();
```

I'd be very interested to see if this works. It's the only logical solution I can think of without having some kind of parent class.

Comment: Sorry not working,Error 1 The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<ModulericaV1.Areas.Hr.Models.HrFileType>.HasMany<TTargetEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ModulericaV1.Areas.Hr.Models.HrFileType,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TTargetEntity>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. c:\users\umutg\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ModulericaV1\ModulericaV1\Models\ModulericaDbContext.cs 20 9 ModulericaV1

Comment: I've just made a minor change to the fluent api which you could test. My theory behind the many to many relationship is to force EF to create a separate table. Out of interest how many related file types could there be?

Comment: actually , i do not want it to create a separate file. It can be more tan 30  :S

Comment: Are you persisting to a sql database? It wouldn't be a new file, only a table holding the relational mapping. Did you try the update?